# Equivalent of WinForm "Dock Fill" for Qt Widgets / Layouts?

Tags: c++, qt4, qt-creator, dock

Starting with Qt (coming from C#, WinForms) I wonder what the equivalent of `Dock: Fill` is (a control shall use all available space)?

The screenshots below show the structure of my simple demo application. The `QTableView` shall expand to the full horizontal dimensions. In a WinForm I'd accomplish this by using `Dock: Fill`. Is there a (similar) solution in Qt?

I have tried the `SizePolicy` and `LayoutSizeRestriction` (`SetMaximumSize`), but with no success.

[image: Demo app]
[image: Demo app UI design]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a little unintuitive the first time around but you just need to set a layout on the `QDialog`. Right-click anywhere on the dialog form and select "Lay out".

Comment: What should I select in "Lay out" to make widget to fill parent's client area? When I select "Adjust size", the widget shrinks itself.